# Volume of solid generated by rotating the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ about the line $x=-2$

Tags: calculus

Prove that the volume of solid generated by rotating the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ about the line $x=-2$ is $4π^2$

Answer (score 1):

The [volume of a torus](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1223388402) is well known. If one uses the notations of the following figure

[image]

then $$V=\frac14(a+b)(b-a)^2.$$

We have $a=3$, $b=1$. That is $$V=4\pi^2.$$